# how do i get Android.Media.SetPreferredDevice() to work

Tags: c#, android, android-mediaplayer

So making a mobile application that works on UWP, IOS and Android but since not all librarys work on every platform I'm using the library based on what device is used by

```
if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.Android) { }
```

And I'm currently only working on the Android part of the application.
I'm using Android.Media to play a single audio file out of multiple speakers. And to do that I'm using a Picker that has the available audio output devices. This part works.

But I'm getting a error while trying to select the PreferredDevice:

```
Java.Lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'no non-static method "Landroid/media/MediaPlayer;.setPreferredDevice(Landroid/media/AudioDeviceInfo;)Z"'
```

The code line that is giving the error is:

```
mediaPlayer1.SetPreferredDevice(audioDeviceInfo);
```

the full method that is being run is:

```
newoutput.SelectedIndexChanged += (changed, args) =>
        {
            Context context = Android.App.Application.Context;
            AudioManager audioMan = (AudioManager)context.GetSystemService(Context.AudioService);
            AudioDeviceInfo audioDeviceInfo = audioMan.GetDevices(GetDevicesTargets.Outputs)[newoutput.SelectedIndex];
            mediaPlayer1.SetPreferredDevice(audioDeviceInfo);
        };
```

I can't find many examples that use the method and they don't usually go with a mediaplayer that is created by button press.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code

```
private AudioDeviceInfo findAudioDevice(int deviceType) {
    AudioManager manager = (AudioManager) this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    AudioDeviceInfo[] adis = manager.getDevices(GET_DEVICES_OUTPUTS);
    for (AudioDeviceInfo adi : adis) {
        if (adi.getType() == deviceType) {
            return adi;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Then set your input:

```
audioRecord.setPreferredDevice(findAudioDevice([newoutput.SelectedIndex]));
```

Comment: I'm doing it, but android ignores the device, and still is using the default one, are there any other configurations needed to make this work?